# BST (binary search tree) not working ?? what is the mistake in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, binary-search-tree

```
class node :
    def __init__(self, data, left= None, right = None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class bst:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        
    def insertNode(self, data):
        
        newnode = node(data)
        
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = newnode
        else:
            current = self.head
            
            while current is not None:
                if data > current.data:
                    current = current.right
                else:
                    current = current.left
            current = newnode
    

bst = bst()
bst.insertNode(5)
bst.insertNode(10)
bst.insertNode(2)
current = bst.head
print(current.data)
print(current.right)
```

I have written a code for the best where the head is always pointing to the root node and there is a while loop which is to find the path to insert the new element to the tree but it is not woking ?? why

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, it may be easier to understand and complete the problem using a recursive approach. We can use recursion to explore the tree, traversing all nodes. Try something like this:

```
def insert(root, data):
    if root is None:
        return Node(data)
    else:
        if root.data == data:
            return root
        elif root.data < data:
            root.right = insert(root.right, data)
        else:
            root.left = insert(root.left, data)
    return root
```

Comment: but I did the same thing using while loop so why it is not working ? for the first node head will always point so that every incoming node will compare with the first node then it will go left or right to find it's position. @JensenMcKenzie

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop before assigning current to either the Left or Right Tree
check whether the Left or Right Child is None, then add a stop condition (break) if the child is None and you have assigned the newnode to it as in the code below

```
class node :
def __init__(self, data, left= None, right = None):
    self.data = data
    self.left = left
    self.right = right

class bst:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    
def insertNode(self, data):
    
    newnode = node(data)
    
    if self.head == None:
        self.head = newnode
    else:
        current = self.head
        
        while current is not None:
            if data > current.data:
                if current.right!=None:
                    current = current.right
                else:
                    current.right=newnode
                    break
            else:
                if current.left!=None:
                    current = current.left
                else:
                    current.left=newnode
                    break
        current = newnode


bst = bst()
bst.insertNode(5)
bst.insertNode(10)
bst.insertNode(2)
current = bst.head
print(current.data)
print(current.right)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are separating the tree and the search into different classes, also, you initialize left and right as None and they will never be giving a value, so your loop will always end setting current as None.
Here is an example of what you are trying to make.

```
class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self, entry, left=None, right=None):
        self.entry = entry
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    
    def insert(self, item, tree):
        if (item < tree.entry):
            if (tree.left != None):
                self.insert(item, tree.left)
            else:
                tree.left = Tree(item)
        else:
            if (tree.right != None):
                self.insert(item, tree.right)
            else:
                tree.right = Tree(item)
```

As you can see I added a check for right and left in case they are None, in which case they are given the item's value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the `current = newnode`. You should not directly assign `newnode` to `current`, which will only rebind `current` to it.

```
def insert(self, data):
    current = self.head
    parent = None

    while current is not None:
        if data == current.data:
            return
        parent = current
        current = current.left if data < current.data else current.right

    newnode = node(data)
    if parent is None:
        self.head = newnode
    elif data < parent.data:
        parent.left = newnode
    else:
        parent.right = newnode
```

Your mistakes are similar to the following:

```
>>> lst = [None, None]
>>> current = lst[0]
>>> print(current)
None
>>> current = 1
>>> lst    # not change
[None, None]
```

`current` simply points to the first item in the list. If you re assign value, you will only make `current` point to other value, which will not modify the contents of the list.

Comment: I did not get your point. I understood your code but what you want to say ?? why I can't  assign new node to current ?

Comment: got it. 